# how to get input from a txt file in java

Tags: java, selenium

I have to various queries like:
`project = 'abc' and status = Closed

project = 'def' and status = Open

project = 'ghi' and status = Open`

I have to call these queries one by one using sendKeys function in selenium. I have to save the queries in a .txt file and perform this action.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

try to use a txt file with following:

```
project;status
abc;Closed
def;Open
```

read in that file in your program like this:

```
private void checkProejctStats(String filePath) throws Exception{
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileInputReader(filePath));
  String line = br.readLine(); //This is the headerline, we don't realy need to know whats inside there.
  line = br.readLine();//means we are going to read the 2nd line.
  while(line !=null){
  String arr[] = line.split(";") //split it in an array
  // TODO: CHECK PROPERLY!
  String projectName = arr[0];
  String projectStatus = arr[1];
  line = br.readLine();//get the next line
}
}
```

Please recognize this is my first post on stackoverflow, never did this before and coded in this editor, so there maybe a problem with some syntax ;)
just let me know, if there are problems.